# Text folding in OpenOffice Writer

Tags: openoffice-writer

I'd like to be able to fold sections of a document in OpenOffice Writer. Is it possible to expand or collapse sections of a document in OpenOffice Writer (or any other word processor?) Many source code editors have this feature, but I haven't yet found this feature in OpenOffice.

Comment: That would be a cool feature.  I found a post about a feature request for it, but I don't see that it has been done.  I think the closest thing it has is the navigator which helps you find and move parts of documents, but won't collapse levels.

Comment: If you're good at writing macros, maybe you could implement at least a very atomic/primitive version of this at the paragraph level by using hidden paragraphs and maybe integrating that with paragraph styles that you could modify on the fly.  http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Hidden_Paragraphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the oo feature call Navigator. It may work for you.
http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2008/03/an-equivalent-o.html

Answer (score -1):

I believe that WordPerfect used to have exactly this feature in it's outlining functionality, but I haven't seen it recently in any other word processor.  It would be a very cool and (I think?) quite obvious feature to add to OpenOffice/LibreOffice...  When I have time in 2037, I'll add it to the codebase... hopefully someone will beat me to it.

Comment: I like how you have your schedule planned out all the way to 2037 ;)